# Calculating the value of integral of $f''(x)$ when given values of $f(x)$ and $f'(x)$.

Tags: calculus, integration

[Here is the original question.](http://puu.sh/aMxdr/38e8602cb4.png)

Suppose that $f(1)=2$, $f(4)=7$, $f'(1)=5$, $f'(4)=3$, and $f''$ is continuous.

Find the value of $\int_1^4 {xf''(x)\,dx}$.

Comment: I keep getting 2 from integration by parts

Comment: The answer 2 is correct. First note that the function  G(x)=xf'-f  is an anti derivative of   g(x)=xf''   (i.e. G'=g). Then the integral from the fundamental theorem evaluates to 
G(4)  -G(1) = 4 f'(4) - f(4) - f'(1) + f(1)
, which can be easily calculated wih what has been given to you.

Answer (score 3):

Integrate by parts

$$\int xf''(x)dx=x\int f''(x)dx-\int\left(\frac{dx}{dx}\int f''(x)dx\right)dx$$

As $\displaystyle\frac{d(f^n(x))}{dx}=f^{n+1}(x),\int f^{n+1}(x)\ dx=f^n(x)+ K$